# Using Logical vector for calling matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, logical-operators

x is a matrix as:

```
x <- matrix(c(4,6,1,8,0,2,3,7,9), 3, 3)
```

I am unable to understand as to how the value of

```
x[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)]
```

is

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    8
[2,]    1    2
```

Can anybody throw some light?

Comment: Try `y <- x[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),]` and then `y[,c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)]` and it should be evident.

Comment: You are providing the row/column index to subset the corresponding elements

Comment: Great, it worked,.. Thanks a Ton @thelatemail!!